# Google Search, First Match wrong part of my website

Tags: web, google-search

when I search for the full name of my website, the first match Google returns is not the index but another page of it. Is it possible to change this behavior. I researched a bit but I'm not sure, which way to go. Will a sitemap change the behavior? Or should I change/add a robots.txt?

Any tips and suggestions welcome.

I'm not sure if this is the right forum. If I should move it somewhere else please tell me where and I will do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about coding. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ is probably the place to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when your subsite is better ranked than your homepage. There can be several reasons:

1. Homepage has some technical problem (invalid HTML, duplicate content, some black-hat technique)
2. The links pointing to your site are pointing to the subsite more offen than to your homepage
3. Homepage is missing quality content
4. If your site is a new one, submit it to indexing, maybe bots did not fully recognize your website yet.

You should go to google's webmaster tools, to see if there is any problem with your homepage. Also you can try one from many SEO analyzers to find out, where the problem is.